# Check to see if an array is already sorted?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I know how to *put* an array in order, but in this case I just want to see if it *is* in order. An array of strings would be the easiest, I imagine, and answers on that front are appreciated, but an answer that includes the ability to check for order based on some arbitrary parameter is optimal.

Here's an example dataset. The name of:

```
[["a", 3],["b",53],["c",2]]
```

Where the elements are themselves arrays containing several elements, the first of which is a string. I want to see if the elements are in alphabetical order based on this string.

Comment: woah... you just changed the question entirely.

Comment: Uh... no I didn't. I swapped out a generic example for a concrete example, that was all. Wanting to be able to compare on some arbitrary component of the array elements was a component of the original question.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It looks like a generic abstraction, let's open `Enumerable`:

```
module Enumerable
  def sorted?
    each_cons(2).all? { |a, b| (a <=> b) <= 0 }
  end
end

[["a", 3], ["b", 53],["c", 2]].sorted? #=> true
```

Notice that we have to write `(a <=> b) <= 0` instead of `a <= b` because there are classes that support `<=>` but not the comparator operators (i.e. Array), since they do not include the module [Comparable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Comparable.html).

You also said you'd like to have the ability "to check for order based on some arbitrary parameter":

```
module Enumerable  
  def sorted_by?
    each_cons(2).all? { |a, b| ((yield a) <=> (yield b)) <= 0 }    
  end
end

[["a", 3], ["b", 1], ["c", 2]].sorted_by? { |k, v| v } #=> false
```

Using lazy enumerables (Ruby >= 2.1), we can reuse `Enumerable#sorted?`:

```
module Enumerable  
  def sorted_by?(&block)
    lazy.map(&block).sorted?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

You can compare them two by two:

```
[["a", 3],["b",53],["c",2]].each_cons(2).all?{|p, n| (p <=> n) != 1} # => true
```

Comment: A quick question: do you know why `ary1 <=> ary2` does what you'd expect (a lexicographical comparison of two arrays) while `ary1 < ary2` and friends fail (since those methods are not defined). Here `p <= n` would be so much nicer to write.. in other words: what's the problem with mixin module Comparable in Array?.

Comment: It's a good question and I'm not sure there's a good reason. Rarely needed, but there would be no cost in including `Comparable`. The ruby-core thread (http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/vframe.rb/ruby/ruby-core/27238?27138-27901+split-mode-vertical ) agrees it should, but I don't think there has been a formal request.

Answer (score 3):

**reduce** can compare each element to the one before, and stop when it finds one out of order:

```
array.reduce{|prev,l| break unless l[0] >= prev[0]; l}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce{|prev,l| break unless l[0] >= prev[0]; l}
=> nil
[3, 2, 1].reduce{|prev,l| break unless l[0] >= prev[0]; l}
=> nil
```

Answer (score 2):

If it turns out the array isn't sorted, will your next action always be to sort it? For that use case (though of course depending on the number of times the array will already be sorted), you may not want to check whether it is sorted, but instead simply choose to always sort the array. Sorting an already sorted array is pretty efficient with many algorithms and merely checking whether an array is already sorted is not much less work, making checking + sorting more work than simply always sorting.

Answer (score 1):

```
def ascending? (array)
    yes = true
    array.reduce { |l, r| break unless yes &= (l[0] <= r[0]); l }
    yes
end


def descending? (array)
    yes = true
    array.reduce { |l, r| break unless yes &= (l[0] >= r[0]); l }
    yes
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the objects and make sure each following element is >= the current element (or previous is <=, obviously) the current element.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work efficiently you will want to sort during insertion.
If you are dealing with unique items, a [SortedSet](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/set/rdoc/SortedSet.html%22SortedSet%22) is also an option.

For clarification, if we patch array to allow for a sorted insertion, then we can keep the array in a sorted state:

```
class Array
  def add_sorted(o)
    size = self.size
    if size == 0
      self << o
    elsif self.last < o
      self << o
    elsif self.first > o
      self.insert(0, o)
    else
      # This portion can be improved by using a binary search instead of linear
      self.each_with_index {|n, i| if n > o; self.insert(i, o); break; end}
    end
  end
end

a = []
12.times{a.add_sorted(Random.rand(10))}
p a # => [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7]
```

or to use the built in sort:

```
class Array
  def add_sorted2(o)
    self << o
    self.sort
  end
end
```

or, if you are dealing with unique items:

```
require "set"
b = SortedSet.new
12.times{b << Random.rand(10)}
p b # => #<SortedSet: {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean here.

Comment: Hey GlyphGryph, I added the monkeypatch for Array above to illustrate the general approach of keeping an array in a sorted state.

Comment: That's... not actually relevant to the question, then. Sorry. I didn't want to sort an array, just see if an array was sorted.

Comment: GlyphGryph, tokland already posted a great way to test for sorted.  My post was in case the issue of speed came up.  In that case, it will usually serve you better to keep your list in a sorted state.  It will reduce your code for checking if the list is sorted to 'nothing' as it will always be sorted ;)

Answer (score 0):

These are all way too hard. You don't have to sort, but you can **use** sort to check. Scrambled array below for demonstration purposes.

```
arr = [["b",3],["a",53],["c",2]]
arr.sort == arr # => false
p arr.sort # => [["a",53],["b",3],["c",2]]
```

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it, but terribly inefficient. If you had an array that started `[2, 1, ...` and had millions of elements, it would be a lot of work to sort the entire array then compare it with the original million element array when you could just look at the first two elements to know that it's not sorted.