# Shorthand for value1 < value2 < value3

Tags: ruby

Is there a shorthand in Ruby to evaluate an expression like

```
value1 = 1
value2 = 2
value3 = 3
value1 < value2 < value3
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `<' for true:TrueClass
# should be true

value2 = 1
value1 < value2 < value3
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `<' for false:FalseClass
# should be false
```

Or do I have to deal with ranges like

```
value1 < value3 && (value1..value3).include?(value2)
```

This way could get pretty unhandy when you have a lot of values.

Comment: Not familiar with Ruby, but doesn't it have a function that checks if an array is sorted?

Comment: No Ruby expert, but wouldn't just `value1 < value2 && value2 < value3` work?

Comment: Yes that would work, I'm just looking for some syntactic sugar ;)

Comment: you can use `include` and add more than one class in it

Comment: you can write something like `[1,2,3].each_cons(2).all?{|a,b| a < b}`, however, I don't know whether there is shorter notation.

Comment: Python has chained comparisons, but Ruby doesn't.

Comment: BTW, your range expression is *not* equivalent to `value1 < value2 && value2 < value3`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check to see if an array is already sorted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015775/check-to-see-if-an-array-is-already-sorted)

Comment: @23tux it would likely be more than syntactic sugar, because in `a < b < c`, `b`  has to evaluated only once, whereas in `a < b && b < c`, `b` might be evaluated twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
value2.between?(value1, value3)
```

Comment: That's equivalent to `value1 <= value2 <= value3`